# Nova actionable_id cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova

Apparently, none of my create functions is working, they all keep throwing:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
'actionable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `action_events` 
(`batch_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `actionable_type`, `actionable_id`, 
`target_type`, `target_id`, `model_type`, `model_id`, `fields`, 
`status`, `exception`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (8db303d9- 
39ca-4858-8d59-30ec1cd51cb7, 1, Create, App\Models\Site, ?, 
App\Models\Site, ?, App\Models\Site, ?, , finished, , 2019-05-16 
09:47:12, 2019-05-16 09:47:12))
```

Basically, it says `'actionable_id' can not be 'null'`.

Here is a sample of my table:

```
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('guid')->unique();

    $table->string('site_title');

    $table->string('site_contents')->nullable();

    $table->integer('record_priority')->default('0');
    $table->integer('record_state')->default('1');
    $table->string('created_by');
    $table->string('updated_by')->nullable();

    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
```

I generate `guid` with `trait`, but for the sake of making this work, I even tried it manually, no luck.

It works just fine when I create it with `tinker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disabled the auto increment from a trait, which was preventing the model from generating an id for the record, here is where my problem was:

```
public function getIncrementing()
{
    return false;
}
```

Removing it or changing with the following one fixes the problem:

```
public function getIncrementing()
{
    return true;
}
```

Prevent that in advance when you are working with Nova, or create it manually.